# jenkins cant connect to android emulator on mac osx

Tags: android, jenkins, user-permissions

I'm playing with jenkins on a macbook pro running el capitan and I've tried a lot of things but the example I'm trying to follow fails every time the emulator tries to run. When I run the job I've created which is supposed to download a Google sample repo on github and run the tests in it I get the following out put until the job terminates itself:

```
    [android] Using Android SDK: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk
    $ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
    * daemon not running. starting it now on port 8611 *
    * daemon started successfully *
    $ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
    $ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -snapshot-list -no-window -avd hudson_en-US_560_1440x2560_android-21_x86_nexus
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
[android] Starting Android emulator and creating initial snapshot
[android] Erasing existing emulator data...
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -ports 8609,8610 -avd hudson_en-US_560_1440x2560_android-21_x86_nexus -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -wipe-data -no-window
_RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:8610
unable to connect to localhost:8610: Connection refused
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:8610 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:8610' not found
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:8610
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:8610 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:8610' not found
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:8610
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:8610 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:8610' not found
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:8610
error: no such device 'localhost:8610'
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:8610
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:8610 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:8610' not found
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:8610
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:8610 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:8610' not found
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:8610
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:8610 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:8610' not found
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:8610
error: no such device 'localhost:8610'
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:8610
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:8610 shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
error: device 'localhost:8610' not found
$ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:8610<code>
```

I read online that the android emulator plugin for jenkins had issues but supposedly was fixed in a release earlier this year. Is it possible that the user that jenkins is acting as has no authority to do anything on my machine so its not able to do anything with the emulator once its up and running? It does look like the emulator is running so I'm pretty stuck at the moment. Should I try to run jenkins on a virtual box setup with Ubuntu? I feel like this simple task I'm trying to accomplish is way more complicated than it should be.

Comment: I ended up running the jenkins instance on a development machine thats hosted on my local network running unbuntu and now it works fine. I think my mac book is locked down to tight and it must be a permission issue preventing jenkins from being able to run the emulator once its up and running.